# Why is this jQuery based website so heavy to load?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm working on my new website.

I have an image build in DIV blocks.
`setBlock(row,  10, '#edc945', 'hair');`

The problem is, the website is quite heavy, I *think* it's because of the setBlock() function, but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts?

Full demo: http://bobvanluijt.com/newAva/ava.html
(it's still in dev ;-)

setBlock function:

```
i=0;
    function setBlock(top, left, color, additionalClass, secondAdditionalClass){
            if(!$('.blockContainer').length){
                $('.container').append('<div class="blockContainer"></div>');
            }
            $('.blockContainer').append('<div class="littleBlock" id="littleBlock__'+i+'" data-row="'+top+'" data-column="'+left+'"></div>');
            $("#littleBlock__"+i).css('background-color', color);
            $("#littleBlock__"+i).css('z-index', i);
            $("#littleBlock__"+i).css('left', Math.round(left*blockSize)+'px');
            $("#littleBlock__"+i).css('top', Math.round(top*blockSize)+'px');
            if(additionalClass!=''){
                $("#littleBlock__"+i).addClass(additionalClass);
            }
            if(secondAdditionalClass!=''){
                $("#littleBlock__"+i).addClass(secondAdditionalClass);
            }
            $('.littleBlock').css('width', blockSize+'px');
            $('.littleBlock').css('height', blockSize+'px');
            i=i+1;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using minified version of jquery js

Comment: @iStimple: If only it was i *increment* e.g. `i++` :)

Comment: @iStimple whoops, it's in the actual code, not in the snip. just updated it ;-)

Comment: @Orion It has nothing to do with that. At best, it would be a littler slower on page load, but the site is always slow (it freezes my browser), even way after page load.

@bvl Thanks for showing the loop initialization, but when is setBlock called ? On what event ? If it's on `mousemove`, you're looking for trouble

Comment: Your website looks so much like a video game I was just accused of playing games at work! *sigh* :)

Comment: It would also be useful if you also posted what browser you are using. I am seeing no problems with Chrome 36. Can you please describe *quite heavy* more? On a side note this question would also fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Spokey no, me neither on Chrome 36. For example an iPad Air, some older machines in general etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here's slight optimised code, but there's probably more that can be done:

```
i=0;
function setBlock(top, left, color, additionalClass, secondAdditionalClass){
    if(!$('.blockContainer').length){
        $('.container').append('<div class="blockContainer"></div>');
    }
    $('.blockContainer').append('<div class="littleBlock" id="littleBlock__'+i+'" data-row="'+top+'" data-column="'+left+'"></div>');
    var littleBlock = $("#littleBlock__"+i);
    littleBlock.css('background-color', color).css('z-index', i).css('left', Math.round(left*blockSize)+'px').css('top', Math.round(top*blockSize)+'px');
    if(additionalClass!=''){
        littleBlock.addClass(additionalClass);
    }
    if(secondAdditionalClass!=''){
        littleBlock.addClass(secondAdditionalClass);
    }
    littleBlock.css('width', blockSize+'px').css('height', blockSize+'px');
    i++;
}
```

By storing the reference to `$("#littleBlock__"+i)` in a variable, the JS doesn't need to search for it again. You can also string jQuery functions together as I have done with the multiple css updates you make.

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

so i think youre problem is that you js libs are all loaded in the head section

means the browser will load all scripts and your whole script before it parses the body, that causes to keep the page blank until the body is parsed and the window onload is executed.

what you can do is put all script right before the `</body>` tag

then you will "immediatly" see "something" i guess

to change the feel of "nothing happens" to "something happens" you could have some spinner gif that you will remove in your document on load function